# Syncing terminal setups across machines (VM, server, etc)

Tags: bash, shell, vagrant

I have recently set up Vagrant on my machine, and the first thing I noticed was that my terminal config was not synced, when I sshed into my server.

For instance I have changed my shell from bash to zsh, which does a lot of beautiful things for me (like removing case-sensitive auto completion). But on my vagrant virtual machine, or on my server, all this cool stuff is now gone. Also stuff like my important aliases is not synced.

Now, what is a proper way to sync stuff like this?

EDIT:

So currently, when I create/remove/edit an alias on my local machine, I have to copy the exact same changes into my VM and all other servers I frequently use. I see this as a very time consuming and unnecessary task.

Comment: The default shell for a user is controlled by the user account configuration on the system (and can be changed with `chsh` or set at user creation time). The shell behaviour (aliases, etc.) is controlled by shell initialization scripts that are just files in your home directory (`.profile`, `.bash_profile`, `.bashrc`, `.zshrc`, etc.). You can just copy those around.

Comment: Added further explanation to my question

Comment: A recent trend has been to use git (or some other version control system) to version the various rc/config files that live in one's home directory. This allows for easy syncing across machines.

Comment: Interesting, do you have any further read on this? I am tottaly new to all this.

Comment: There have been any number of blog posts around the internet on this topic over the past few years. I don't know of any specifically offhand. I don't do this myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I do is version control my dotfiles and I keep them on github. Dotfiles are just the files in your root that start with a dot in the name such as .bashrc or .zshrc. They are "invisible" files, so you have to use ls -a instead of just ls to see them.

Here are my dotfiles: https://github.com/aharris88/dotfiles

When I get on a new machine, I just clone the repository to ~/dotfiles
Then, I have a bash script in there called setup.sh that backs up any old dotfiles that might already be in root into ~/dotfiles_old. Then it creates symlinks to the files that are in ~/dotfiles.

It also installs zsh and oh-my-zsh if it isn't already. It should work for linux or mac os x.

Here is an article describing how to version control your dotfiles: http://blog.smalleycreative.com/tutorials/using-git-and-github-to-manage-your-dotfiles/

Another thing that I do to get a new mac ready is use kitchenplan: https://github.com/kitchenplan/kitchenplan, which can sync a lot more settings, but this probably isn't what you're asking about. Here is my kitchenplan config: https://github.com/aharris88/kitchenplan-config

Comment: Really cool - thanks for your answer. Could you maybe referer to an article where this is described? Or could I persuade you to write one on the subject?I like that it automaticly install zsh and setup your aliases. This is exactly what I want as a start. All the other stuff (vim, etc, seems overkill).

Comment: I added a link to my answer

Comment: still use this answer to-date  thanks